# Does verite Timeline perform well with huge data sets?

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, timeline

I need to visualize a huge set of data inside a timeline. I found '[verite Timeline](http://timeline.verite.co/)' looks promising but I don't have any experience with it, using really many data sets. Is here anyone who could tell me about the performance of this tool or tell me about a better solution?
thnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in their [FAQ](http://timeline.verite.co/#faq) ( fourth question ):

> **How many entries will work best in TimelineJS?**
>
> Timeline is optimized for up to 100 entries preferably more like 20-30. Anything else may cause a loading issue.

Now maybe you could not respect their limit, but I do not think that using it with "lots of tons of data" would be a good experience. :) ( well, you could load only 100 entries at a time, but I'll leave this up to you )

I'm not able to suggest you an alternative, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry ..
again, but in English ....

Verite timeline supports JSON as a data source, I have a project in MVC3 and route the data source to a controller. You obviously can do it differently for instance from a Web Service, or Ria, etc ....

To start the timeline you, put a timeline initial script in the head or body:

```
 var timeline = new VMM.Timeline();  
 timeline.init("http://localhost:9306/TimeLine/Json");
```

You create classes to store the data structure, this will allow you to return the instance of the class in the same format json from the driver:

```
public class json
```

{
     public timeLine timeline 
     { 
      get; 
      set; 
     } 
   }

```
public class timeLine
{
public string headline { get; set; }
public string type { get; set; }
public string startDate { get; set; }
public string text { get; set; }
public asset asset { get; set; }
public List<date> date { get; set; }
}

public class asset 
{
public string media { get; set; }
public string credit { get; set; }
public string caption { get; set; }
}

public class date
{
public string startDate { get; set; }
public string endDate { get; set; }
public string headline { get; set; }
public string text { get; set; }
public asset asset { get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
   public ActionResult Json()
   {
    json j = new json();

    j.timeline = new timeLine();
    j.timeline.headline = "TimeLine";
    j.timeline.type = "default";
    j.timeline.startDate = DateTime.Now.Year + "," + DateTime.Now.Month;
    j.timeline.text = "<p>Time Line de todo el contenido.</p>";

    j.timeline.asset = new asset();
    j.timeline.asset.media = "";
    j.timeline.asset.credit = "Desarrollador por Mauricio Farias www.ald.cl             mfarias@ald.cl";
    j.timeline.asset.caption = "Develop By Mauricio Farias";

    j.timeline.date = new List<date>();
    //for each de tiempos
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        date d = new date();
        d.startDate = DateTime.Now.Year + "," + DateTime.Now.Month + "," + i;
        d.endDate = DateTime.Now.Year + "," + DateTime.Now.Month + "," + (i + 1);
        d.headline = "Headline date for date in timeline";
        d.text = "<p>text in date for date in timeline</p>";

        d.asset = new asset();
        d.asset.media = "";
        d.asset.credit = "credit in asset for date in timeline";
        d.asset.caption = "caption in asset for date in timeline";
        j.timeline.date.Add(d);
    }

        return Json(j, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

At the hearing or in your case may be an aspx or html page (remember to put the css):

```
<div id="timeline">
</div>
<script src="../../Content/assets/js/timeline-min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Content/assets/js/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Mauricio! Thnx for the answer. It is nice of you to give me a short introduction. BUt what I was really looking after was the questio  if thies timeline tool performs well with a huge set of data. So if you use this tool and lots of tons of data, will it still scroll fine in the browser? Or will it slow down the system?
thnx!